# Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP HD Camera on Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, camera

I have a problem on my HP Elitebook 840 G7 with my builtin camera.
The camera is detected but the picture is just black.

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6bf Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP HD Camera

# hwinfo --usb | grep -A 50 Chicony
Model: "Chicony Electronics HP HD Camera"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x04f2 "Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd"
Device: usb 0xb6bf "HP HD Camera"
Revision: "0.13"
Serial ID: "200901010001"
Driver: "uvcvideo"
Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
Device File: /dev/input/event20
Device Files: /dev/input/event20, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.2-event-ir, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._HP_HD_Camera_200901010001-if02-event-ir
Device Number: char 13:84
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v04F2pB6BFd0013dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip01in02"
Driver Info #0:
Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Attached to: #35 (Hub)
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: First there is no version of Ubuntu called 20. What software are you trying to use with the camera? Have you checked the HP site to see if there are any know issues with this camera running Ubuntu?

Comment: It should be Ubuntu 20.04 and tried with skype,cheese and zoom.All HP links and googles lead to Windows ...

Comment: It is possible there is no driver for this camera in the kernel you are running or for that matter any kernel. What kernel are you running?

Comment: 5.10.0-1049-oem

Comment: As that is an oem kernel check on HP web site and see if they have a newer one. Personally I do not know if an OEM kernel can be replaced by a generic one. Maybe someone else will read your question and know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle built-in privacy shutter just above the camera. (It looks like a CDS cell when closed, if you know what that looks like.) Shift it to the left and you should be able to see yourself.